# Why is GGally::ggpairs significantly slower in RStudio vs. base R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, ggally

Per the title, does anyone know why rendering a `ggpairs` plot from the [`GGally`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/index.html) package takes significantly longer in RStudio vs. base R (or terminal)?

Example:

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
ggpairs(mtcars)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Running this in RStudio on my machine takes on the order of 5 times longer than base R. I have experienced the same slow down regardless of OS (Windows vs. Mac).

Are there any workarounds?

Other packages?

Specifically, how to render something like:
 `GGally::ggpairs(iris, color = "Species")` quickly without leaving RStudio?

Comment: Is this just RStudio's internal graphics device? What happens if you start up a free-standing graphics device? Is it still slow? [not sure how you start one in Windows R, on Unix R its "X11()"....]

Comment: @Spacedman Looks like it. Using `x11()` then plot then `dev.off()` speeds things up considerably within RStudio.

Comment: It may be because the RStudio graphics device does anti-aliasing and transparency.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues, and spent some time trying to figure out why. I found four significant issues (not an exhaustive list). If your situation is like mine, then 1 and 2 are your main concerns.

1. The IDE. RStudio performs ggpairs slower than R.
2. Your computing environment. I don't have the resources to test this extensively, but we're most likely talking about GPU, since this is a graphics processing issue.
3. Number of variables. More variables = exponential growth in time.
4. Sequential operations. If you are working on a low-power machine, you could slow execution with too many requests.

You can read more on my github here: https://github.com/zstachniak/Elapsed-Time-Pairwise-Functions/blob/master/ggpairs.md